# Extensible factory method in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, factory

### The problem

Imagine having a base class, in a framework, that defines several pure virtual methods, which is effectively an interface. Users of this class inherit from it and implement its method as usual.

What I'm trying to obtain is provide a mechanism to the framework for instantiating derived class via an uniform factory method that return an instance of the derived class.

### The try

I thought of putting a static `base* get_one()` method inside the base class to be reimplemented, but of course, being static, it can't be virtual.

### The goal

The final goal is to provide a base class for a so-called driver, so that users can write their own implementations and the framework can, when asked to do so, return device instances using that particular driver.

Comment: As stupid as the question may be, I can't understand the down-vote. I tried to explain the problem and the goal extensively with all the needed details.

Comment: have you looked at the all of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern ?

Comment: How does it know which derived class to use?

Comment: An id/key (previously registered with some mechanism) passed to the factory would be OK.

Answer (score 1):

A simple (and I suppose common) approach is to "register" an instance of the derived class at the (abstract) base class, which then serves as a factory. You may then decide whether the driver shall be a singleton or whether the instance is  a "template" from which a copy is drawn every time a caller request a driver.
A simple implementation could look as follows:

```
// Framework part:
class Driver {
public:
    static Driver* getDriver() {
        return driver;  // return the instance (or make a copy, if desired)
    };
    static void registerDriver(Driver *driver) {
        Driver::driver = driver;
    }
private:
    static Driver *driver;
};

Driver *Driver::driver = nullptr;


// Customization part:
class MyDriver : public Driver {

};

MyDriver mySingleDriver;

int main()
{
    Driver::registerDriver(&mySingleDriver);
    return 0;
}
```

In production, you'd probably use managed pointers and implement a more sophisticated "singleton" approach. But the principle should be clear...

Comment: The problem is that there are n drivers and n*m possible devices. "Driver" is just a base class for many possible drivers, hence the need for an "extensible" factory. This "solution" considers only one derived class.